# もう used with 〜ている

Tags: grammar, aspect

In the following sentence:

> 特別警報が出たときは、**もう**被害が出**ている**かもしれないぐらい危険なときです。

what is the meaning of もう?

Comment: Among other meanings, もう can mean "already", which is very often what it is when used with -ている.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of もう in this sentence is `already`.